# R - histogram rectangles line thickness

Tags: r, histogram

How can I get the actual lines (that form the many rectangles) on a histogram to be thicker? I would like to avoid using `ggplot`.

Here is some code that generates a histogram so that we have a reproducible example:

```
h = hist(rnorm(100),plot=F)
plot(h,lwd=4) #note, lwd does not work :(
```

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can set the line width with `par()`:

```
opar <- par(lwd=2)
plot(h)
par(opar)
```

[image: histogram plot]